# Timed out waiting for device error on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Everything was working great until I decided to move my root partition to LVM...

I managed to get it moved over and after a few times running update-grub got the system back up and running. I now however had an issue when I go to boot. There is a long pause and then get into maintenance mode or Ctrl+D to continue. When I remove the splash screen I can see that for each of my LVM devices I get 'Timed out waiting for device'. I checked my /etc/fstab out and I cant see anything wrong with it:

```bsh
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
# UUID=ca597288-3202-4da2-9c04-416fa24a8a94 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/lync-root   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/mapper/lync-boot   /boot   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/mapper/lync-home   /home   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/mapper/lync-var    /var    ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/mapper/lync-var_log    /var/log    ext4    errors=remount-ro   01
/dev/mapper/lync-tmp    /tmp    ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/mapper/lync-swap   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=3AB3-E4A6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

If I hit ctrl+d the systems continues and boots up.

I'm also seeing strange errors in dmesg which may or may not be related:

```bsh
[  281.393023] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 39] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[  281.393034] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  281.393035] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  281.393037] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  281.393038] pcieport 0000:02:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[  321.361950] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[  321.361956] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  321.361960] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d10] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  321.361962] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
```

Any help would be great!

### **Edit:**

When I boot without my USB-C Dell D6000 dock connected everything is ok and I can boot right in no issues.